# Static asp:CheckBoxList evaluating all checkmarks as false

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist, aspx-user-control

I have a simple static CheckboxList in my form :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false" CodeBehind="Groupes.aspx.cs" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" Inherits="WebApp.Form" %>
    <form runat="server">

          <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text ="Text1" Value="1"  ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text ="Text2" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text ="Text3" Value="3" Selected="True" Enabled="false></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </form>
```

On a button click event (PostBack) I am trying to retrieve the values of the Selected CheckBoxList items in code behind as shown below :

```
List<string> selectedValues = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected).Select(li => li.Value).ToList();
```

But selectedValues.Count is always 1. Only the ListItem that is Disabled whose Selected is set to "True" is counted :

```
<asp:ListItem Text ="Text3" Value="3" Selected="True" Enabled="false></asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: Everything is looks fine and it's work while I test.

Comment: can you please add more related code which may possible to cause of problem.

Comment: I was performing a CheckBoxList1.ClearSelection() on another button click event that precedes the one in which I am trying to get the selected ListItems. But even with that gone, the selectedValues .Count always returns 1 (only the Disabled ListItem whose Selected is set to "True" in the form is counted  )